# One to Many/many to many SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with mysql and running into a little confusion. I have created two tables `academy` and `courses`. I am needing help in determining how to structure the table fields. For example the `one to many` schema. One academy can offer many courses and a course can be offered with many academies. Is the structure for the tables below correct?

```
create table academy
(
  academy_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  course_id int()  NOT NULL ,
  name varchar(25) not null,
  primary key (id),
 );
CREATE TABLE course
(
course_id     int(11) not null auto_increment,
course_name   VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL ,
primary key (course_id),
foreign key (academy_id) REFERENCES academy (academy_id) on delete cascade
);
```

Example of desired result

```
    id Name                  Course

    1  The Alamo School      125 Intro to Programming 
    2  Bearcat High School   125 Intro to Programming
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really need is a table for the academies, one for the courses and a relationship table where you can store the many-to-many relationships. I leave to you the query to get the result you are looking for :)

```
CREATE TABLE academy
(
  academy_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(25) not null,
  primary key (id),
 );

CREATE TABLE course
(
course_id     int(11) not null auto_increment,
course_name   VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL ,
primary key (course_id),
); 

CREATE TABLE accademy_course
(
  academy_id int(11) not null,
  course_id     int(11) not null ,
  primary key (academy_id, course_id),
  foreign key (academy_id) REFERENCES academy (academy_id) on delete cascade,
  foreign key (course_id) REFERENCES course (course_id) on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: This makes sense now. I needed a that third table to create the many to many relationship. Would this apply if I had instructors involved?