# How to design this Database part?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

I have a users table and a groups table.
My question is, how can I implement a system in groups so that I can acces all the users id's which are part of that group.

Example: I have John, Mary and Alex in the users table. John is id 1, Mary is 2 and Alex is 3.

Now how can I add these users to the group users? I can't just add fields like "user_1", "user_2", "user_3".  What if the group has 1000 members?

Comment: A database *designer* you say?

Comment: @DainisAbols I'm kind of a beginner. I'm not sure how to do this. Normally I'd use an array but... as MySQL doesn't accept arrays, I don't know how to design this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19871295/2545927

Comment: Fun fact, according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html and since integers are size 4, you should be able to squeeze in up to 16384 columns in the form of user_1, ..., user_16384 :)

Comment: Well, truly that is possible, but it's sure not the way to go :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a groups table and users table. add groupid as foreign key in users table
Like:

```
tbl_group : id: int(11) Auto Increment - P.K
          : group_name: varchar(500)

tbl_users : id: int(11) Auto Increment - P.K
          : user_name: varchar(20)
          : group_id:  int(11) - Foreign Key - // Foreign Key to groups Table.
```

If you want many users want to join many groups then

```
tbl_group : id: int(11) Auto Increment - P.K
          : group_name: varchar(500)

tbl_users : id: int(11) Auto Increment - P.K
          : user_name: varchar(20)

tbl_user_group : id: int(11) Auto Increment - P.K
               : group_id:  int(11) - Foreign Key - // Foreign Key to groups Table.  
               : user_id:  int(11) - Foreign Key - // Foreign Key to usersTable.
```

Comment: Thanks. Your new edit fits my question perfectly.  This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Please upvote and mark the question that worked for you as the most helpful answer (the green tick under the voting buttons).

Comment: Upvoting is not yet possible for me but the "green tick" has been awarded. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

you need another table that contains at least a user_id and a group_id

the relation between users and groups is m:n - a user can be part of multiple groups and a group can contain multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

You can add two Database tables:

```
tbl_users
id
group_id
name
```

AND

```
tbl_groups
id
name
```

save group id in the user table.

Comment: Yes, but I'd want a user to be able to join more groups so it's not only group_id...

Comment: @MerdescuR., I have added another answer, please check it!

Answer (score 1):

Answer to support multiple groups for a user:

```
tbl_users
id
name
```

AND

```
tbl_groups
id
name
```

AND

```
tbl_user_groups
id
user_id
group_id
```

And thus we can have an **n:n** relationship (**many users** to **many groups**).